# How do I return a reference to the value inside an optional struct field?

Tags: rust, reference, option-type

I am trying to improve the `Cacher` type described in [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html). One of the improvements suggested states that `Cacher` should be usable with many types. To do this, I have written the following code:

```
struct Cacher<T, U>
where
    T: Fn(&U) -> U,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<U>,
}

impl<T, U> Cacher<T, U>
where
    T: Fn(&U) -> U,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, U> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            value: None,
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: &U) -> &U {
        match self.value {
            Some(v) => &v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.value = Some(v);
                &v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.value.0` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:21:15
   |
21 |         match self.value {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&self.value`
22 |             Some(v) => &v,
   |                  -
   |                  |
   |                  data moved here
   |                  move occurs because `v` has type `U`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0515]: cannot return reference to local variable `v`
  --> src/lib.rs:22:24
   |
22 |             Some(v) => &v,
   |                        ^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return reference to local variable `v`
  --> src/lib.rs:26:17
   |
26 |                 &v
   |                 ^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `v`
  --> src/lib.rs:26:17
   |
24 |                 let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
   |                     - move occurs because `v` has type `U`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
25 |                 self.value = Some(v);
   |                                   - value moved here
26 |                 &v
   |                 ^^ value borrowed here after move
```

I imagine this is because `v` is local to the function. However, given that the actual data exists within the struct which exists beyond the `value` method, is it not possible to return reference to this data in any way? If not this way, then what would I have to do to get the functionality of a `Cacher` that owns the calculated data and returns the references whenever required?

Comment: it looks like [`Option::get_or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with) would help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. You just need to return the reference to the object **inside** the `Option`:

```rust
struct Cacher<T, U>
where
    T: Fn(&U) -> U
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<U>,
}

impl<T, U> Cacher<T, U>
where
    T: Fn(&U) -> U
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, U> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            value: None,
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: &U) -> &U {
        if self.value.is_none() {
            let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
            self.value = Some(v);
        }
        self.value.as_ref().unwrap()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de532a8e56614377fb940f9b5abf7348)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler and slightly more efficient alternative is to use [`get_or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with):

```
fn value(&mut self, arg: &U) -> &U {
    let calculation = &self.calculation;
    self.value.get_or_insert_with(|| calculation(arg))
}
```